# Find all IIS web-servers in a domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, domain

Hej,

is there a way to list/find all web-servers with IIS-installed in a Windows domain?

Like this can be done with DHCP-mmc, which allows to view and manage all DHCP servers in a domain.

thx.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that reports the installed features and roles of a Windows Server. Loops the script, iterating through a list of the servers in the domain and you will get a list of all the IIS servers.

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/787-list-installed-server-roles-and-features